how to search a multiple level nested tags in ES
mapping of the tags:
"tags": {
      "properties": {
        "children": {
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          },
          "type": "nested"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      },
      "type": "nested"
    }

I want to search: tags.value match 'L1 Tag Name' and tags.children.value([]string infact) contains 'L2 Tag Name'.
This is search request I wrote, but it does not work, it cannot find level 2 tags:
GET material/_search
"bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "match": {
                                            "tags.value": "L1_Tag_Name"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "nested": {
                                            "path": "tags.children",
                                            "query": {
                                                "bool": {
                                                    "must": [
                                                        {
                                                            "match": {
                                                                "tags.children.value": "L2_Tag_Name"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }


I'm assuming that you have not configured a custom analyzer and tokenizer.
There are 2 potential problems with your setup as it seems

the standard (default) tokenizer will lowercase your value fields and for example "L1_Tag_Name" will not be matched
you need an extra nested clause in your query for the "tags.value"

You should definitely take a look at the docs on how your text in the values fields gets tokenized and decide what is best for you. For example, using the whitespace tokenizer would preserve the case and create tokens every time a space is encountered in your text.
To setup your environment, I created an index like so:
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/idx1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
            "properties": {
                "children": {
                "properties": {
                    "value": {
                    "type": "text"
                    }
                },
                "type": "nested"
                },
                "value": {
                "type": "text"
                }
            },
            "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'

And indexed a document like so:
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/idx1/_doc/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "tags": {
        "children": {
            "value": "L2_Tag_Name"
        },
        "value": "L1_Tag_Name"
    }
}
'

So, using the default mapping (which I assume you also have) the query should be:
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/idx1/_search"  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "size": 1,
    "query" : {
        "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": { "tags.value": "l1_tag_name" }
                        },
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "tags.children",
                                "query": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [
                                            {
                                                "match": {
                                                    "tags.children.value": "l2_tag_name"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'

Notice the extra nested clause and that the tag values are lowercased.
And the result would be something like:
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.5753642,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "idx1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "tags" : {
            "children" : {
              "value" : "L2_Tag_Name"
            },
            "value" : "L1_Tag_Name"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

You should also consider using the keyword type in your mapping instead of text you are using now as that would work with exact matches and if that's what you want, it will be more performant.
